# Is it possible to use a script to enable edition in more than one sheet on Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to enable edition in more than one sheet to 60 users (using e-mail).
The user need to edit a few cells and all the other the edition need to be blocked.
Example: all the user should have the edition enable in sheets X, Y and Z, and the range of cells enabled to edition is B6:Q50. All the other cells need to be blocked and only the owned can edit.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please add more context on your post such as the research you've done or what you've tried so far. Also, if I understand your post correctly, you want to add multiple editors by their email addresses to multiple sheets inside of a spreadsheet file and only allow them to edit a specific range (e.g. B6:Q50) and the rest are restricted to the editors. Is this correct?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. sorry. It's my first question here. I searched a solution to this problem but I didn't find it. Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***

On your main Google spreadsheet file, you can [create a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) and try this tweaked script below:

> This script was based from [Protect spreadsheet then unprotect specific cells and ranges with script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525225) & article of [addEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditorsemailaddresses) method.

***Script:***

```
function main() { //Main function to run
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  addEditors();
  for(var x=0; x<sheets.length; x++){
    unlockCertainRanges(sheets[x]);
  }
}

function addEditors(){ //Function to add editors
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var emails = [
    'test1@example.com',
    'test2@example.com',
    'test3@example.com'
  ];
  sheet.addEditors(emails);
}

function unlockCertainRanges(currentSheet){ //Function to unlock certain ranges on your sheets
  var sheet = currentSheet;
  // Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    protection.remove();
  }

  var protection = sheet.protect();
  //restrict editors to owner
  protection.getRange().getA1Notation();
  var eds = protection.getEditors();
  protection.removeEditors(eds);

  //set unprotected ranges
  var ranges = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var data = ["B6:Q50"]; // ADD YOUR RANGES HERE TO BE EDITABLE
  data.forEach(res => { //LOOPS INTO EVERY ARRAY CONTAINING SPECIFIC RANGES
    ranges.push(sheet.getRange(res));
    protection.setUnprotectedRanges(ranges); //REMOVES THE PROTECTION ON THE RANGE
  });
}
```

***Sample Result:***

*After running the `main` function, the emails added on `addEditors` function are automatically added as editors of the file & they'll be abe to edit range `B6:Q50` and the rest of the cells will be protected (only the owner of the spreadsheet file will be able to edit):*

[image]

***Sample Images:***

[image]

> **Image 1:** A user is not allowed to edit cell `A1` (outside of `B6:Q50` range on all sheets)

[image]

> **Image 2:** User is allowed to edit cell `B6` (within `B6:Q50` range on all sheets)

Comment: Thank you! It worked like I wanted! Just a question: if I change 'var data = ["B6:Q50"]' to 'var data = ["B6:Q50; "A1:A2"]', users can edit A1 and A2?

Comment: You're welcome, yes, you can follow this sample structure instead if you want to add more ranges (separated by commas) ----> var data = ["B6:Q50","A1:A2"];